# Brackets keep sneaking back in! Why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, io

I have a list of lines in a file that' I'm reading in and they look like this:

```
[something]:[here]
[something]:[here]
[something]:[here]
[something]:[here]
```

Now the code below basically determines if anything in the list is in the TextBox, and if the textbox contains a "key", then the key will be replaced with the key's value.

```
        string key, value, tempLine = "";

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(list))
        {
            string line;
            string[] split;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Do something with the line.
                tempLine = line.Replace("[", "");
                tempLine = tempLine.Replace("]", "");

                split = tempLine.Split(':');
                key = split[0];
                value = split[1];
                    key = key.Replace(@"[", "");
                    key = key.Replace(@"]", "");
                    value = value.Replace(@"[", "");
                    value = value.Replace(@"]", "");
                if (((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Contains("[" + key + "]"))
                {

                    ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text = ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Replace(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem I am having is that, no matter what I do --- the brackets ([ and ]) keep coming back!

Please, is there something wrong with the way i am trying to rid my string of brackets? How do I get them to go away?

Comment: Can you explain "coming back", perhaps with an example?

Comment: Define "coming back"  where are they appearing?

Comment: You've erased them twice, should be enough. Describe what happens where and when.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input file contents and what key and value end up as?

Comment: Maybe try erasing them for a third time?

Comment: Your last two lines of code are essentially `if ("[foo]".Contains("foo")) Text = "[foo]".Replace("foo", "bar");` If you replace `foo` in `"[foo]"` with `bar`, then the result is obviously `"[bar]"`.

Comment: only way to deal with zombie brackets ] is to cut off their heads, like so ˩

Comment: I've erased thebrackets twice - what I mean by "coming back" is that even after replacing the brackets with empty string, the brackets still appear!!!

Comment: OK, now describe "appear".

Comment: No need to be pedantic here, you should know exactly what I meant by that.

Comment: Not pedantic but your question does leave out the crucial 'actual' part. You do _not_ describe what actually happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you are searching a placeholder composed by [key] into your textbox, but when substitute the value only replaces the key, keeping `[]` intact.

You must replace your code with this...

```
if (((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Contains("[" + key + "]"))
{
    ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text = ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Replace("[" + key + "]", value);
}
```

And don't replace twice the `[]` characters. It is not necessary.

Using your code as baseline, the resulting code must be:

```
string key, value, tempLine = "";

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(list))
{
    string line;
    string[] split;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Do something with the line.
        split = line.Split(':');
        key = split[0];
        value = split[1].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");

        if (((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Contains(key))
        {
            ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text = ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Replace(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only necessary to do the `Replace` on the value. There's no need to do it for the line or the key.

Comment: Sorry, @HuorSwords, this didn't work at all.

Comment: I just saw the update, am trying the updated now.

Comment: Perfect! I just tried the updated version and it works very well. I'm so happy :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text = ((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Text.Replace("[" + key + "]", value);
```